# Parsing content from head tag from jQuery AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get content from head tag, but it seems not working. It looks like Jquery has stripped out   tag. Please help with a solution. Many thanks.

```js
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/echo/html/",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            var temp = $('<div></div>').append($.parse.html(data));
            
            var headContent = temp.find('head').html();
            $('#head-content').html(headContent);
        },
        data: {
            html: '<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>test site<\/title><link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" /><\/head><body><ul><li><a class="disabled" id="link">content<\/a><\/li><\/ul><\/body><\/html>'
        }
    });
});
```

```css
p {
    border: 1px solid red;
    
}
```

```html
<p id="head-content">Content from head tag here</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `DOMParser()` to convert string to html element, using jQuery `$.parseHTML(data)` will return `Array [ <title>, <link>, <ul> ]`

```js
html = '<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>test site<\/title><link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" /><\/head><body><ul><li><a class="disabled" id="link">content<\/a><\/li><\/ul><\/body><\/html>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
var headContent = htmlDoc.head.innerHTML;
document.getElementById('head-content').value = headContent;
```

```css
#head-content {width: 90%; min-heigth: 100px}
```

```html
<textarea id="head-content">Content from head tag here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be revealed in jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation:

> jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

As such, I assume you **cannot** retrieve the `<head>` content via [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (despite such wording not being mentioned in the `.ajax()` documentation).

Comment: I had to use .ajax() in order to wait the whole next page got loaded. Is .load() can do as same as .ajax()?